# ValidationSummary does not exist in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to Style a WPF DataGrid.  I copied the Control Template from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), into a resource dictionary.  I can't get it to compile, because it says,

"ValidationSummary does not exist in XML namespace"

I have all the PresentationCore and PresentationFramework assemblies referenced in my project.

I think I might need "System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll" but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). You cannot use that in WPF. You have to find the WPF counter part for the same class.

Comment: Turns out I needed this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The page you are referring is for `Silverlight` but in case you want the customize the styles and templates for `WPF`, refer to the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248.aspx).